# Using CSS declaration of * {z-index:1;} to simplify all IE z-index issues

Tags: html, css, z-index

IE does funny things with z-index. When dealing with rollover navigation, I always went through the thought process of "Ok. . . need to give this element position:relative, with this z-index, and the same to this one, then give this a higher z-index. . ." it always turned out to be a pain.

Then I thought, why not just give every element on the page a z-index of 1 to start, making it the same across all browsers? That way I only have to apply z-index:2 to my header and *voila*. I tried adding this to a couple of websites and saw no adverse effects.

I'm thinking I will just add this to my typical reset stylesheet that I use on every project. Does anyone see a problem with this?

```
* {z-index:1;}
```

Comment: offtopic: you may want to go and Accept some answers from your previous questions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every element by default has a z-index of zero, so I can't see how changing everything to one will help you.

Also using the * to run through every page element is very inefficient and will slow down your page.

Comment: Because IE (IE6 and I believe 7 as well) give everything a z-index of 0 by default, whereas other browsers give them a z-index of "auto". 

So for example, say we have a header that has a rollover navigation that needs to go in front of the content below it, if you give one element a z-index of 2 then it's not necessarily going to put it in front of other elements unless you assign its siblings a lower z-index. In the case of some versions of IE, you have to also assign z-indexes to parent elements. This just simplifies it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that using * to apply to every element with CSS slows down the page at all - I've been using Eric Meyer's reset stylesheet for years, and that applies default stylings to just about every element on the page and people have felt this was acceptable practice. I could be wrong though, I've only tested this out on a couple of websites.

Comment: Using the * selector to run through every element on the page undoubtedly takes longer than targeting just the classes you need, but it's not a huge difference so it it may not be a concern for you. Interestingly I use the Yahoo reset stylesheet which targets elements by name, rather than using *.

Comment: My reset stylesheet selects certain elements as well, it's just a lot of them. Maybe just selecting all divs on the page with  div {z-index:1;} would be a better idea, since divs are typically what is used for building the structure of the website.